# C++: Array of member function pointers to different functions

Tags: c++, pointers, function

I have a class A which contains member functions foo() and bar() which both return a pointer to class B. How can I declare an array containing the functions foo and bar as a member variable in class A? And how do I call the functions through the array?

Answer (score 21):

The member function pointer syntax is `ReturnType (Class::*)(ParameterTypes...)`, so e.g.:

```
typedef B* (A::*MemFuncPtr)(); // readability
MemFuncPtr mfs[] = { &A::foo, &A::bar }; // declaring and initializing the array
B* bptr1 = (pointerToA->*mfs[0])(); // call A::foo() through pointer to A
B* bptr2 = (instanceOfA.*mfs[0])(); // call A::foo() through instance of A
```

See e.g. [this InformIT article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=142) for more details on pointers to members.

You might also want to look into [Boost.Bind](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.boost.org%2Fdoc%2Flibs%2Frelease%2Flibs%2Fbind%2Fbind.html%3Fsess%3D94fbb4fa5cfd2b2071c3be193acb355d&ei=jBJ1TKHfOs_GswaPm9HzBQ&usg=AFQjCNGgcgK3JvAil5XXHY4AGdIBa5HNrQ&sig2=EfmYABM4suSY4e_oqlu3QA) and [Boost.Function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/function.html) (or their TR1 equivalents) which allow you to opaquely bind the member-function-pointers to an instance:

```
typedef boost::function<B* ()> BoundMemFunc;
A instanceOfA;
BoundMemFunc mfs[] = { 
    boost::bind(&A::foo, &instanceOfA), 
    boost::bind(&A::bar, &instanceOfA) 
};
B* bptr = mfs[0](); // call A::foo() on instanceOfA
```

To use such an array as a member, note that you can't initialize arrays using the member initializer list. Thus you can either assign to it in the constructor body:

```
A::A {
    mfs[0] = &A::foo;
}
```

... or you use a type that can actually be initialized there like `std::vector` or `boost::array`:

```
struct A {
    const std::vector<MemFuncPtr> mfs;
    // ...
};

namespace {
    std::vector<MemFuncPtr> init_mfs() {
        std::vector<MemFuncPtr> mfs;
        mfs.push_back(&A::foo);
        mfs.push_back(&A::bar);
        return mfs;
    }
}

A::A() : mfs(init_mfs()) {}
```

Comment: @DeadMG: I mentioned the TR1 version but went for the Boost version as it has the broadest availability. I personally consider the C++0x versions as not widespread enough and the new standard is also not finalized yet.

Comment: Ah, so you did. Since I got a C++0x compiler myself, I'm not used to seeing the boost variants.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for are **pointers to member functions**. Here is a short sample that shows their declaration and use:

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
  B(int foo): foo_(foo) {
    std::cout << "Making a B with foo_ = " << foo_ << std::endl;
  }
  ~B(void) {
    std::cout << "Deleting a B with foo_ = " << foo_ << std::endl;
  }
  int foo_;
};

class A {
public:
  A(void) {
    funcs_[0] = &A::foo;
    funcs_[1] = &A::bar;
  }

  B* foo(void) {
    return new B(3);
  }

  B* bar(void) {
    return new B(5);
  }

  // Typedef for the member function pointer, for everyone's sanity.
  typedef B* (A::*BMemFun)(void);
  BMemFun funcs_[2];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  A a;
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    A::BMemFun func = a.funcs_[i];
    // Call through the member function pointer (the .* operator).
    B* b = (a.*func)();
    delete b;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The [C++ FAQ section on pointers to member functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html) is where I found all this information.

Answer (score -1):

C++ that's not ancient (read: C++11 and later) makes this all easier. In modern C++, you can do

```
#include <vector>
class B;
class A {
   public:
    B* foo() {
        // return something;
        return nullptr;
    }

    B* bar() {
        // return something;
        return nullptr;
    }
    
    //C++ 11: functional brings std::function, which has zero overhead 
    //but is actually a useful type with which one can work
    std::vector<std::function<B*()>> container;

    /* [=]() { return foo(); }
     * that's a lambda. In practice it "compiles away", i.e. calling
     * the lambda function is the same as calling foo or bar directly
     * Note how [=] means we're passing in "this", so that we can 
     * actually call foo().
     */
    A() : container{{[=]() { return foo(); }}, {[=]() { return bar(); }}} {}
};
```

([Try on godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dhxW665KM))

Here's a more [complete example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aPfKzrTqr) showcasing what to do with these.

---

An architectural remark: Be careful with pointers to non-static member functions. What happens if your instance of `A` gets destroyed, but you still have a function handle to a member function? Right, hell freezes over: There's no object anymore to which this method belongs, so results are catastrophic.