# I have array of pointers of methods my class, but I cannot call my method. Code are below

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

 
class FooBar{
public:
        typedef void(FooBar::*OnDio)(void);

    void OnDio0Irq( void ){
        printf("dio0\n");
    };
    void OnDio1Irq( void ){
        printf("dio1\n");
    };
    FooBar(){
        OnDio  dioArray[] = {&OnDio0Irq, &OnDio1Irq};
        
    };
    
    OnDio  *dioArray[2];
private:
            
};
 
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
        typedef void(FooBar::*OnDio)(void);
        void (FooBar::*foo)(void);
    OnDio *myPtr;
    FooBar *fb = new FooBar();
    
    myPtr = *(&fb->dioArray[0]);
    foo = (OnDio &)(myPtr[0]);
    (foo)();//me need call fb->dioArray[0]()
    (*myPtr)(); // ?
 }
```

How can I call a function from an array?
In my code i have error:

> [Error] must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'foo
> (...)', e.g. '(... ->* foo) (...)'
>
> [Error] must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in
> '* myPtr (...)', e.g. '(... ->* * myPtr) (...)'

Comment: Look up the section titled **Pointers to member functions** at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a pointer to member function (ptmf), you need an instance and the ptmf, together.

OnDio is already typedef'ed to be a pointer type, so you may not want OnDio pointers.

Also, you initialize a local temporary in the constructor, not the dioArray of "this" instance.

This answer is also helpful: [C++: Array of member function pointers to different functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565825/c-array-of-member-function-pointers-to-different-functions)

Here is your code, corrected to call dio0 through a pointer to member function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

class FooBar {
public:
    typedef void(FooBar::*OnDio)(void);

    void OnDio0Irq(void) {
        printf("dio0\n");
    };
    void OnDio1Irq(void) {
        printf("dio1\n");
    };
    FooBar() {
        // declaring a local OnDio array just masks the actual member and then it gets tossed
        // need to initialize this instance, not some local temporary
        dioArray[0] = &FooBar::OnDio0Irq;
        dioArray[1] = &FooBar::OnDio1Irq;
    };

    OnDio dioArray[2];
private:

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // need instance
    FooBar fb;
    // need pointer to member function
    FooBar::OnDio func = fb.dioArray[0];
    // call pointer to member function using instance
    (fb.*func)();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>



class FooBar {
public:
    typedef void(FooBar::*OnDio)(void);
    OnDio dioArray[2];
    void OnDio0Irq(void) {
        printf("dio0\n");
    };
    void OnDio1Irq(void) {
        printf("dio1\n");
    };
    FooBar() {
        dioArray[0] = &FooBar::OnDio0Irq;
        dioArray[1] = &FooBar::OnDio1Irq;
    };


private:

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    FooBar* fb  = new FooBar();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(fb->dioArray) / sizeof(fb->dioArray[0]); i++)
    {
        (fb->*fb->dioArray[i])();
    }

}
```